# Using csv files as a dataset for Keras

Tags: python, keras

I want to construct an AI system to identify by my current data if there is a fault or not.

One csv file is one measurement from a certain time with current values and serves as one sample with the label "fault" or "not-fault"

I was woundering how to proceed the files for my NN.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# List of file names
file_names = ["arc3A_000.csv", "arc3A_001.csv", "arc3A_002.csv", "non-arc3A_000.csv", "non-arc3A_001.csv", "non-arc3A_002.csv"]

# Number of rows to skip (including the header row)
skip_rows = 9

# Create an empty list to hold DataFrames for each file
dfs = []

# Loop through the file names and read each CSV file into a DataFrame
for file_name in file_names:
    csv_file_path = rf"XXXXXXX\arc\{file_name}"
    column_names = ["Time", "Current"]
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file_path, names=column_names, skiprows=skip_rows)
    # Add a new column to represent the labels based on the file name
    df["Label"] = "arc" if "arc" in file_name else "non-arc"
    dfs.append(df)

# Combine all DataFrames into a single DataFrame
combined_df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)

# Encode labels (convert "arc" and "non-arc" to numerical representation)
label_mapping = {"arc": 1, "non-arc": 0}
combined_df["Encoded_Label"] = combined_df["Label"].map(label_mapping)

# Extract features (X) and labels (y)
X = combined_df[["Time", "Current"]].values
y = combined_df["Encoded_Label"].values

# Split the data into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Create TensorFlow datasets
batch_size = 64
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train)).shuffle(len(X_train)).batch(batch_size)
test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_test, y_test)).batch(batch_size)


So one csv- file is one sample with the label "arc" or "non-arc". I am confused how i can do this like this, even its only proceeding 64 data points from each csv....
```

Comment: If you are using tensorflow.keras for modeling, you don't necessarily needs to construct tf.data.Dataset. One can directly train using the numpy arrays X_train,y_train and validate the model using X_test,y_test

Comment: thank u for the answer! u mean directly using `model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))` or?

Comment: I was wondering if i am using it in a right way. One csv file is one sample. By `# Extract features (X) and labels (y)
X = combined_df[["Time", "Current"]].values
y = combined_df["Encoded_Label"].values ` i am confused by the name "label" because my label is "arc" or "non-arc" for the whole file.

Comment: Okay, by one sample means, does it have only one datapoint ? Or, are you implying that one '.csv' file contains only for one label ?

And yes, you can directly fit the numpy arrays as the way you posted in the previous comment

Comment: One .csv file is related to one sample - it contains a certain amount of datapoints but every csv is only one sample with one label

Comment: The background is that the system should proceed a time series of 10ms -  every csf file is related to 10ms time series. after 10ms it should deside for a fault or not a fault

Comment: it is very similar to https://keras.io/examples/timeseries/timeseries_classification_from_scratch/
each measurement contains 100 datapoints and should lead to one classification

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
X = []
y = []
#Loop through the file names and read each CSV file into a DataFrame
    for file_name in file_names:
        csv_file_path = rf"XXXXXXX\arc\{file_name}"
        column_names = ["Time", "Current"]
        df = pd.read_csv(csv_file_path, names=column_names, skiprows=skip_rows)
        X.append(df["Current"].values) #Assuming the sequence is in order. Otherwise sort timewise, based on its datatype
        label = 1 if "arc" in file_name else 0
        y.append(label)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
```

Now each datapoint is a series, you can use sequential models like RNN or LSTM and fit the data using

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

If you are using normal feed-forward layer, then each datapoint can be considered as one input to the input layer, and do the modeling.